# My custom extension is not visible on admin panel Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2

I installed my custom extension via composer.
I can confirm that app/code/vendor/package_name generated on the server by composer.
However,on admin panel under stores/configuration/advanced I can not see my extension.

What I've tried so far are as following ;

1. Flushing Magento 2.0 cache and disabling caching
2. Changing extension file permissions to 777
3. Deleting files under var/cache manually
4. Logging out and logging in again

None of them solved my problem.
How can I see my custom extension under admin stores / configuration / advanced on Magento 2.0 ?

I am not sure if it any helps but I posted my config.xml and module.xml

Thanks in advance,

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Fusion_CODFee" schema_version="0.0.1"></module>
</config>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Fusion_CODFee>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Fusion_CODFee>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me `setup_version` is missing from `module.xml`. It should be like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Fusion_CODFee" schema_version="0.0.1" setup_version="0.0.1"></module>
</config>
```

Comment: `schema_version` is no longer required.

Answer (score 0):

you shoul try php bin/magento setup:upgrade command so that your magento upgrade itself with the new extension, also check for config.php in app/etc folder ,your module should be there if is active in case it is not then under array() tag add this "Fusion_CODFee=>1" and then run upgrade command in your rootdirectory, it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried following code that's working for me please have look

```html
Fusion\CODFee\etc\module.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
 <module name="Fusion_CODFee" setup_version="2.0.0">
 </module>
</config>
```

Now next you have to register your module with  registration.php

create registration.php under Fusion\CODFee\registration.php and put below code inside it.

```html
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Fusion_CODFee',
    __DIR__
);
```

Now clearing you cache and if still not working then fire below command from your root directory  of magento installation

If your system is ubuntu then => sudo php bin\magento setup:upgrade or for window system remove sudo

then change permission and that's it

Let me know if still have any query